# Custom map marker showing on android device but not on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I'm building a cross-platform app in React Native Expo, and am using react-native-maps to render a map with custom markers. I'm using the 'icon' prop on the Marker component to render a png image, and in addition to this, the Marker displays a child `Text` element, as follows:

```
              <Marker
                key={i}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: gig.location.latitude,
                  longitude: gig.location.longitude,
                }}
                icon={require('../assets/map-pin-50pc.png')}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate("GigDetails", {
                    venue: gig.venue,
                    gigName: gig.gigName,
                    image: gig.image,
                    blurb: gig.blurb,
                    isFree: gig.isFree,
                    genre: gig.genre,
                    dateAndTime: { ...gig.dateAndTime },
                    tickets: gig.tickets,
                  });
                }}
              >
                <Text style={styles.gigInfo_text}>{gig.genre}</Text>
              </Marker>
```

On android devices, the custom marker image and the text are rendered as expected. On iOS devices however, only the text is rendered, and the 'icon' image cannot be seen. Any suggestions as to why?

I tried importing the image and passing it to the icon prop as follows:

```
import mapPinImage from '../assets/map-pin-50pc.png'

...
...

icon = {mapPinImage}
```

This didn't work either. I also checked the size of the image which was 41x62 pixels, with a size of  2.41kb - well below apple's maximum size requirements.

For context, here's the entire component that render the map:

```
import { FC } from "react";
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import { mapStyle } from "../util/mapStyle";
import { useGigs } from "../hooks/useGigs";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import { mapProps } from "../routes/homeStack";
import { Switch } from 'react-native-paper'
import mapPinImage from '../assets/map-pin-50pc.png'


type MapScreenNavgationProp = mapProps['navigation']

interface Props {
    navigation: MapScreenNavgationProp
}

const GigMap:FC<Props> = ({ navigation }):JSX.Element => {
  const [selectedDateMs, setSelectedDateMs] = useState<number>(Date.now());
  const [isSwitchOn, setIsSwitchOn] = useState(false);
  const gigs = useGigs();


  //generates current date in format DD/MM/YYYY
  const selectedDateString:string = useMemo(() => {
    const formattedDate = format(new Date(selectedDateMs),'EEE LLL do Y')
    return formattedDate
  }, [selectedDateMs]);

  const currentDay:string = useMemo(() => {
    const formattedDay = format(new Date(selectedDateMs),'EEEE')
    return formattedDay
  },[selectedDateMs])

  const currentWeek:string = useMemo(() => {
    const formattedDay = format(new Date(selectedDateMs),'LLLL do Y')
    return formattedDay
  },[selectedDateMs])

  //Filtering through gigs to return only current day's gigs
  const gigsToday = gigs.filter((gig) => {
    const formattedGigDate = format(new Date(gig.dateAndTime.seconds * 1000), 'EEE LLL do Y')
    return formattedGigDate === selectedDateString;
  });

  const freeGigsToday = gigsToday.filter((gig) => {
    return gig.isFree === true
  })

  const gigsToDisplay = isSwitchOn ? freeGigsToday : gigsToday
  
  //increments date by amount
  const addDays = (amount:number):void => {
    setSelectedDateMs((curr) => curr + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * amount);
  };

  const onToggleSwitch = () => setIsSwitchOn(!isSwitchOn);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View testID="gigMapHeader" style={styles.headerText}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText_main}>{currentDay}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.headerText_sub}>{currentWeek}</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.imageText}>
        <Text style={styles.subHeader}>Tap on the</Text>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={require("../assets/map-pin-new.png")}
        />
        <Text style={styles.subHeader}>
          icons on the map to see more gig info
        </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
        <MapView
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: -41.29416,
            longitude: 174.77782,
            latitudeDelta: 0.03,
            longitudeDelta: 0.03,
          }}
          style={styles.map}
          customMapStyle={mapStyle}
        >
          {gigsToDisplay.map((gig, i) => {
            return (
              <Marker
                key={i}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: gig.location.latitude,
                  longitude: gig.location.longitude,
                }}
                icon={require('../assets/map-pin-50pc.png')}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.navigate("GigDetails", {
                    venue: gig.venue,
                    gigName: gig.gigName,
                    image: gig.image,
                    blurb: gig.blurb,
                    isFree: gig.isFree,
                    genre: gig.genre,
                    dateAndTime: { ...gig.dateAndTime },
                    tickets: gig.tickets,
                  });
                }}
              >
                <Text style={styles.gigInfo_text}>{gig.genre}</Text>
              </Marker>
            );
          })}
        </MapView>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.buttonOptions}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addDays(-1)} style={styles.touchable}>
          <AntDesign name="caretleft" size={36} color="#000000" />
          <Text style={{ fontFamily: "NunitoSans", color: "#000000",marginLeft:'8%' }}>
            Previous day
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addDays(1)} style={styles.touchable}>
          <AntDesign name="caretright" size={36} color="#000000" />
          <Text style={{ fontFamily: "NunitoSans", color: "#000000",marginRight:'8%' }}>
            Next day
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style = {styles.buttonAndSwitch}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("List")}
          style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>List View</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style = {styles.switch}>
            <Switch value={isSwitchOn} onValueChange={onToggleSwitch} color = '#377D8A' />
            <Text style = {styles.switch_text}>Free Events</Text>
          </View>
      </View>

    </View>
  );
};

const {width:screenWidth, height:screenHeight} = Dimensions.get('window')
const mapWidth = screenWidth * 0.9 //this sets width to 90%
const mapHeight = mapWidth /0.91 //this set height  based on the figma map aspect ratio of 0.91



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    // flexDirection: "column",
    // alignItems: "center",
    flex:1
  },
  map: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%'
  },
  mapContainer:{
    marginTop: '5%',
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    width: mapWidth,
    height: mapHeight,
    flex:1,
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        borderRadius:26,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.3,
        shadowRadius: 2,
      },
      android: {
        overflow: 'hidden',
        borderRadius:26,
        elevation: 4,
      }
    })
  },
  gigInfo: {
    // backgroundColor: '#68912b',
    // marginTop:20
  },
  gigInfo_text: {
    fontSize:10,
    color:'black',
    fontFamily:'NunitoSans',
    paddingTop: 25,
    textAlign:'center',
    fontWeight:'bold'
  },
  gigInfo_text_genre: {
    color: "white",
    fontFamily: "Helvetica-Neue",
    transform: [{ translateY: -5 }],
  },
  headerText: {
    color: "black",
    fontSize: 25,
    marginTop: '0%',
    marginLeft: '7%',
    fontFamily: "NunitoSans",
    marginBottom: 10,
    
  },
  headerText_main: {
    fontFamily: "NunitoSans",
    fontSize:25,
    lineHeight:34.1
  },
  headerText_sub: {
    fontFamily:'LatoRegular',
    size:14,
    lineHeight:16.8
  },
  callout: {
    width: "auto",
    height: "auto",
    backgroundColor: "azure",
  },
  buttonOptions: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginTop:'4%',
    width:'100%'
  },
  buttonOptionsText: {
    margin: 5,
  },
  image: {
    height:20,
    width:14,
    marginHorizontal:3
  },
  imageText: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginLeft:'7%',
    marginTop:27
  },
  touchable: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  subHeader: {
    fontFamily: "LatoRegular",
    color: "#747474",
    size: 12,
    lineHeight: 17.04
  },
  button:{
    flexDirection:'column',
    width:115,
    height:37,
    marginLeft:'7%',
    backgroundColor:'#377D8A',
    borderRadius:8,
    justifyContent:'center',
    marginTop:'6%'
  },
  buttonText: {
    color:'#FFFFFF',
    textAlign:'center',
    fontFamily: 'NunitoSans',
    fontSize:16,
    lineHeight:22
  },
  buttonAndSwitch:{
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'space-between'
  },
  switch:{
    marginRight:'6%',
    transform: [{translateY:7}]
  },
  switch_text: {
    fontFamily: 'LatoRegular',
    fontSize:10,
    transform:[{translateY:-10}]
  }
});

export default GigMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace icon image data props with image Icon as child component to Marker.

```js
<Marker
    key={i}
    coordinate={{
      latitude: gig.location.latitude,
      longitude: gig.location.longitude,
    }}
    icon={require("../assets/map-pin-50pc.png")}
    onPress={() => {
      navigation.navigate("GigDetails", {
        venue: gig.venue,
        gigName: gig.gigName,
        image: gig.image,
        blurb: gig.blurb,
        isFree: gig.isFree,
        genre: gig.genre,
        dateAndTime: { ...gig.dateAndTime },
        tickets: gig.tickets,
      });
    }}
  >
    <Image
      source={require("../assets/map-pin-50pc.png")}
      style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}
    />
    <Callout>
      <Text style={styles.gigInfo_text}>{gig.genre}</Text>
    </Callout>
  </Marker>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to have the text as showing by default if possible. If it's within a callout, it's only shown when the marker is pressed. S basically I want the icon image and text together. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But if the text is long it will cause UI issues by overlapping other markers. Avoid `genre` being too long.

Comment: Would you mind providing a code example? It's been pretty tricky to get both text/icon working on apple devices.

Comment: Check my StackOverFlow profile. We can schedule a short meeting together

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/users/12431576/fiston-emmanuel